# Understanding the difference between null and '\u000' in Java

Tags: java, null, char

I read in a book *(Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel, 4th edition, page 47)* that `null` is equal to `'\u000'`. And then I was wondering what exactly does `'\u000'` really mean.

As per my understanding null was nothing or absence of anything. And `'\u000'` comes in contradiction with this definition.

Can anyone clarify this issue about `null` and `'\u000'`?

Comment: presumably it was sth like ``char null = '\u000';``

Comment: yes Hachi.The book is Thinking in Java-Bruce Eckel.

Comment: char ‘\u0000’ (null) in page 47 of 4th edition.

Comment: @ashwinsakthi In that context I suppose the author refers to the char with ASCII value 0, not Java's null keyword.

Comment: Please clarify your question by editing it, rather than by providing additional information in comments.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The language specification is where null is defined, and it says

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null, which has no name. Because the null type has no name, it is impossible to declare a variable of the null type or to cast to the null type. The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null type. The null reference can always be cast to any reference type. In practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference type. [*--Link to documentation (Section 4.1)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)

and

> The null type has one value, the null reference, represented by the literal null, which is formed from ASCII characters. A null literal is always of the null type. [*--Link to documentation (Section 2.3)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html)

Rather a circular sounding definition, but the value of `null` is the *null reference* itself - just another pointer. The value of the null reference isn't really relevant and is presumably up to the implementor, but zero or some other value that can't be confused with another object address is likely.

Confusion may be caused here because there is a character value called the **null character** with value `\u0000`. This is the default value for type char.

Comment: @waldyr.ar - Sorry. I still don't get it. Can you please explain in plain English or with a diagram ? Btw, links are not working anymore.

Comment: @waldyr.ar - Can you please explain what is the use of `\u000` in the code in this comment. I am posting the code here because SO might downvote me. `private final String path; private static enum PathStatus { INVALID, CHECKED };
    private transient PathStatus status = null;
final boolean isInvalid() {
        if (status == null) {
            status = (this.path.indexOf('\u0000') < 0) ? PathStatus.CHECKED
                                                       : PathStatus.INVALID;
        }
        return status == PathStatus.INVALID;
    }`

Comment: \u0000 is the null character in Unicode. It's different from `null` in Java, but has a similar meaning. @testerjoe2 Your code means that if the path contains the null character, it's status is `INVALID`, otherwise it's `CHECKED`.

Answer (score 18):

`\u000` would be the unicode representation of a character with ASCII code 0, but has nothing to do with `null` as used by Java.

Answer (score 11):

'\u0000' 
decimal equivalent is 00
Char equivalent is NUL.

From Character in Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

```
static char MIN_VALUE 
      The constant value of this field is the smallest value of type char, '\u0000'.
```

This is the unicode value, that in CHAR is equivalent to NULL, ie it is the NULL CHARACTER, rather than being the literal NULL.

Comment: what is the significance of NULL character?

Answer (score 1):

`null` is a literal and you can see the specification which says
*in practice you can simply pretend that it's "merely a special literal that can be of any reference type".*

as @assylias said what you read was surely not out of java :)