# whitespace will not get removed

Tags: java, string, whitespace, stringbuilder, removing-whitespace

Assume there is a `url="www.example.com/"`. Using the following code I want to remove the trailing slash but it leaves a blank at the end of string (which by the way I do not know why) and using the rest of the code, I am trying to remove the white space but it will not work.

```
    String url="http://www.example.com/";
    int slash=url.lastIndexOf("/");


    StringBuilder myURL = new StringBuilder(url);

    if(url.endsWith("/")){
       myURL.setCharAt(slash, Character.MIN_VALUE );
       url=myURL.toString();
    }

    url=url.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Just get the substring. `url = url.substring(0, slash)`.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz I think you should post it as an answer

Comment: why complicating things if you can achieve this in one line:-System.out.println(url.replace("/",""));

Comment: `Character.MIN_VALUE` mean `null` so replacing last value with this result in something like space or a box character so you can use `deleteCharAt(index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `\s+` does not match `Character.MIN_VALUE`. Use `' '` instead.

```
String url="www.example.com/";
int slash=url.lastIndexOf("/");


StringBuilder myURL = new StringBuilder(url);

if(url.endsWith("/")){
   myURL.setCharAt(slash, ' ');
   url=myURL.toString();
}

url=url.replaceAll("\\s+","");
System.out.println(url);
```

But why don't you just remove the `/` ?

```
String url="www.example.com/";
int slash=url.lastIndexOf("/");

StringBuilder myURL = new StringBuilder(url);
myURL.deleteCharAt(slash);
System.out.println(myURL);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to trim it: `url = url.trim();`

Comment: So, what the heck is the use of all those answers for removing whitespaces if a trim can fix it?

Comment: Your code will resolve this error, and is perfectly fine.  Might I suggest also explaining to the OP why his code is leaving a whitespace in the first place?

Comment: @user3049183 trim will only remove whitespaces at the beginning or end of your string. In your case thats all that you need. But sometimes it might be necessary to remove all whitespaces, even those in the middle of a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
String url="www.example.com/";    
if(url.endsWith("/")){
            url = url.substring(0, url.length()-1);
        }

System.out.println(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setCharAt() you should use deleteCharAt().
But the simplest way to do the job is

```
String url="www.example.com/";
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be the use of the setCharAt method.

This method replaces a char with another char. So even though you have replaced it with the Character.MIN_VALUE which at first glance may appear to represent the literal Null it is actually still a unicode character ('\0000' aka the null character).

The simplest fix would be to replace...

myURL.**setCharAt**(slash, Character.MIN_VALUE );

with...

myURL.**deleteCharAt**(slash);

Further info regarding the null character...

[Understanding the difference between null and '\u000' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195628/understanding-the-difference-between-null-and-u000-in-java)

[what's the default value of char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909333/whats-the-default-value-of-char)

This is my first answer so apologies if I've not kept to conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the empty space is caused by `Character.MIN_VALUE` being interpreted as a space.

Try this.  Its a little cleaner than your current replace code and will leave no space.

```
if(url.endsWith("/")){
    url = url.trim().substring(0, url.length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace you code inside your **if-block** with the below one

```
url = url.substring(0, url.length()-1).trim();
```

Then I hope you will no longer need that **StringBuilder** object also.

So your final code will look like

```
String url="www.example.com";
url = (url.endsWith("/")) ? url.substring(0, url.length()-1) : url;
System.out.print(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you complicating things, if this can be achieved in single line

```
String url="www.example.com/";
url=url.replace("/","");
System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: I had the same thought initially.  Unfortunately this solution won't work in a general case for URLs.  (Any URL with other slashes in it.