# How to eliminate Windows special character`^@` in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, windows, csv

My work doing some processes like

- Load data from csv to MySQL(migration replica table - From MSSQL)
- read MySQL data to make a VO Java class
- When VO edited, will save to MySQL(another table)

The problem is ...

- open the CSV file, I can see special character `^@`
- After `LOAD DATA` Then do `SELECT` query, the data does not contains `^@`
- However, I read same data via Java and restore to another table It store `\u0000`

How to remove this `\^0000` ?

The best solution in my current situation, I would like to handle in java code...

FYI,

- MSSQL dump made on Windows OS (From Client)
- MySQL Load data on Windows (Local dev environment)
- The program which perform migration is on CentOS(Server)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195628/understanding-the-difference-between-null-and-u000-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I believe your export is dumping BIT values as actual "bit characters", i.e the BIT `0` becomes `\0` and the BIT `1` becomes `\1`.

For convenience (and speed) you could probably parse the CSV using [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) with this setting:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.setSkipBitsAsWhitespace(false); //prevents treating \0 and \1 as blank space

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
```

You can then proceed to replace `\0` and `\1` to characters `0` and `1` respectively on the columns where they appear.

Hope this helps.