# why Zero & null of char data type is treated as same in java

Tags: java, null, char, zero

i have to perform some task by checking if a char have a zero value and if a char has null '\u0000 value but don't know java compiler is treating both as same
here's the sample code

```
char nullTest = 0; 
System.out.println(nullTest == '\u0000'); //it is giving true
```

if i initialize it as `nullTest = '0'` then it is giving false, but in my program I frequently assigns numbers & null `'\u0000'` to this variable due to which it gives runtime errors,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195628/understanding-the-difference-between-null-and-u000-in-java

Comment: `if i initialize it as nullTest = '0' then it is giving false`. Because `'0'` is not `0`. It has some (Unicode?) code, which differs from `0`. On the other hand `'\u0000'` is, by definition, a character with code `0`. I've no idea why you call this `null`.

Comment: @dyukha it's 48.

Comment: the question is why 0 and '\u000' are treated as same, how can i treat them differently we all know both are two different things,

Comment: \u000 would be the unicode representation of a character with ASCII code 0, Dont get confused with **\u**.Actually java reads unicode with this prefix

Comment: `\u0000` specifies a *character* with the hex value `0000`. That's the *definition* of that syntax. See Java Language Specification [3.2. Lexical Translations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2): *"A Unicode escape of the form `\uxxxx`, where `xxxx` is a hexadecimal value, represents the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is `xxxx`."*

Comment: @JunaidAhmed they are the same. The only difference in a representation. You can either assign a character to a `char` variable or its ASCII or Unicode code. `char c = 51;` and `char c = '3';` assign the very same value to variable `c`.

Comment: now i got it, thanks @ivan

Answer (score 2):

The notation \uXXXX primarily only occures in .java and .properties files. There it is read as a **Unicode code** point. Unicode text (=using all kind of special characters) often uses the UTF-8 format (though also sometimes UTF16LE and UTF16BE are used).

So if you initialise a character in java using `char nullTest = 0;` without giving the single quotes it is internally treated as `nullTest = unicode of 0` which is `'\u0000'` but if you initialize a character with quotes like `char nullTest= '0'` it is treated a Character of string and stored as '0'

Comment: `\uXXXX` is not a Unicode code point. It is a UTF-16 code unit. See JLS [3.2. Lexical Translations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2): *"A Unicode escape of the form `\uxxxx`, where `xxxx` is a hexadecimal value, represents the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is `xxxx`."*