# NodeJS - regex not working as expected. \0 is interpreted as \u0000

Tags: javascript, node.js

The data is actually coming from a websocket and I want to extract the `1234` from it...

```
var data = 'TEST|1234\0'
console.log(data);

Output: 
TEST|1234
```

As a result regex isn't working as expected either.

```
var regex = /\|(.*?)\\/;
var re = new RegExp(regex, "g");
var extractedNumber = msg.match(re);
console.log(extractedNumber);

Output:

null
```

But if I change the regex to see what is happening I see that `\0` is becoming `\u0000`

```
var regex = /\|(.*)/;
var re = new RegExp(regex, "g");
var extractedNumber = msg.match(re);
console.log(extractedNumber);

Output:

[ '|1234\u0000' ]
```

This answer says that `\u0000` would be the unicode representation of a character with ASCII code 0.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195709/6926996

Comment: Don't know if that's your problem, but just know that when you declare `var data = 'TEST|1234\0'`, the end string does not actually contain a "\". It escapes the `0` to treat it as an ascii code. If you want it to contain a "\", you need to escape it: `var data = 'TEST|1234\\0'`

Comment: I don't think we can escape it either.. since in order to escape I'd first need to store it in a variable. The data is coming from a websocket.

Comment: yea that's right. it is in `TEXT|NUMBER\0` and I want to extract the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use regex if you know the pattern,

```
var data = 'TEST|1234\0'
console.log(+(data.slice(data.indexOf('|') +1, data.indexOf('\\'))))
```

`+` for convert it to number, `slice` from `'|' +1` until `\` (have to write twice `\\` at the `indexOf` ...)